# What's wrong with this code to find heightInInches?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium

After click, a calculated BMI is shown as 0.3; expected answer was 22.8

Code snippet in question:

```
calculateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var feet = feetField.value;
    var inches = inchesField.value;
    var heightInInches = (feet * 12) + inches;
    bmiDisplay.text = ((weightField.value / (heightInInches * heightInInches)) * 703).toFixed(1);
});
```

heightInInches should equal 68, **not 608**. Seems like somehow feet (5) is being multiplied by **120** instead of 12 and then tacking on the inches (8) at the end, but I don't quite understand why that's happening, and why it's hiding from me when I step through the code?

Debugger shows the correct values for **feet**(5) and **inches**(8) in the formula but an incorrect value assigned to **heightInInches** after the calculation.

[Link to BMI formula](http://www.bmi-calculator.net/bmi-formula.php/)

I think I formatted the question correctly; long time listener, first time caller. I've just been staring at it too long... I had screenshots of my UI and the debugger but I had to remove those images from the post. Ok, thanks for checking it out.

Comment: You need to convert the strings to numbers.

Comment: You might also do well to write a function that calculates BMI based upon your three numeric inputs (pounds, feet, inches), and test that by itself.  Then test separately the part that fetches these numbers from the controls.  Then you can put them together in your event handler.  It might help make for more maintainable code, and might help you debug these issues by yourself as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding:

```
var feet = parseFloat(feetField.value);
var inches = parseFloat(inchesField.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

`inches` is a string so when you do the + operator, it concatenates it. You can simply do

```
var heightInInches = (feet * 12) + inches*1;
```

and it will treat it as a number.

Comment: You can also do it as `+inches`, but I suppose `+ +inches` doesn't exactly look nice.